# Authentication of different types of user of same name in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model of teacher and student . If I created a Student and again create a teacher with same name and email and stuffs, It gets created .. Can't be a teacher and student of same people in a college. How to apply in rest api?

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to solve this, depending on your requirements and preference.

One way would be at database level with constraints. In this case you'd have to create model with all people regardless of their status and add additional boolean field that differentiates between Students and Teachers. This would look like this:

```
class People(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField()
```

[`unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) means that email must be unique throughout the table and if you try to add another person with the same email, `IntegrityError` will be raised.

There is also a possibility to use unique over several fields with [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) like this.

```
class People(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('first_name', 'last_name'),)
```

This means that first_name and last_name together must be unique.

Another approach would be to check if student or teacher is already in one or the other table before saving with `filter()` and [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists).

```
teacher_exists = Teacher.objects.filter(teacher=something).exists()
student_exists = Teacher.objects.filter(student=something).exists()
```

`exists()` returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.

Comment: The problem is there are two different tables for teacher and student. So the second method by filtering will be handy?

Comment: Sure. When someone tries to add a person to either tables, you check if this person is already in student or teacher table and return error message or save a person.